# Multiple ListRows for each Header on BrowseFragment - Leanback library

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-tv, leanback

I'm getting started with Leanback support for our app.
As per UI requirements I need to add multiple list rows corresponding to each header, it's exactly like what Youtube App does on Android TV. Default **ListRowPresenter** seems to be rendering only one list row and its header. Is there any presenter that supports multiple list rows? I'm thinking on the lines creating a custom presenter with RowsFragment embedded in each item, correct me if my approach is wrong.[image]

Comment: Just a note - you might want to check out my answer below. The newest version of Leanback solves this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37800789/1759443

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Leanback team has recently added in support for multiple `ListRow`s for one `HeaderItem` in version `24.0.0` of the library. It allows you to supply a `RowsFragment` that maps to the `HeaderItem`. You can see an example of it in their [Leanback showcase](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase). Specifically, [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/page/PageAndListRowFragment.java) is the file where they provide an example.

There is a new `PageRowFragmentFactory` that you will need in your `BrowseFragment` which specifies which Fragments map to which `HeaderItem`s. Like so:

```
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(Object rowObj) {
        Row row = (Row)rowObj;
        mBackgroundManager.setDrawable(null);
        if (row.getHeaderItem().getId() == HEADER_ID_1) {
            return new SampleFragmentA();
        } else if (row.getHeaderItem().getId() == HEADER_ID_4) {
            return new WebViewFragment();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Invalid row %s", rowObj));
    }
```

You can just have the above method return an instance of a `RowsFragment` and now you'll have the `RowsFragment` which contains multiple `ListRow`s map to just one `HeaderItem`.

As of right now you can get access to this goodness through version 24.0.0 of Leanback with the below line in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:24.0.0
```

You might get a warning, but for now it can be safely ignored.

There is also a ton of other really cool stuff in version `24.0.0` of Leanback like snazzy transition animations and cleaner APIs. It can all be found in that sample project I linked above. There is also a [talk from Google I/O](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFHIfQy8_Wc) which covers more of the additions.

Comment: @Kyle Venn : I did the same as that sample project above but search button not auto hide.
 ( Image: https://i.imgur.com/mCeCj0o.png )
Can you help me ?
Can you help me ?

Comment: @MrSiro, I'm happy to take a look - but I'll be more helpful if I can see your code. Can you open up a new Stack Overflow question with your code and provide me with the link? The hiding and showing happens through the `BrowseFragment` talking to the `TitleView`. And that should all work automatically.

Comment: @KyleVenn : I solved the problem. Thank you. Can you help our the error at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576744/android-tv-searchfragment-error-speechrecognizer

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any presenter that supports multiple list rows?

Not that I know of. The problem is that BrowseFragment only accepts children that subclass `Row`. For this reason, there can only be single rows (and their respective headers) for each entry in BrowseFragment.

> I'm thinking on the lines creating a custom presenter with
>   RowsFragment embedded in each item, correct me if my approach is
>   wrong.

As I just mentioned, I doubt that creating a custom presenter would help.

The only solution I have been able to come up with so far is simply creating a custom version of BrowseFragment (by manually extending the `RowsFragment` and `HeadersFragment` classes) so that it supports any type of fragments.

If you're interested, I wrote a series of articles on the process 
https://medium.com/building-for-android-tv/

and a base project that offers the custom version of BrowseFragment https://github.com/dextorer/BuildingForAndroidTV

I'm also considering writing a library to ease the use of this custom component.

Comment: Perfect, you pin pointed the solution of my problem. Loved all your Android TV articles, saved me tons of hours of source code inspection.

Comment: Dextor, Any lead to create Custom Details Fragment with different UI (Two Header Item) would be really helpful.