# Android Leanback library BrowseFragment

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I want to use a BrowseFragment inside an activity along with another fragment.
The purpose of the other fragment is to have a listview, on each selected item the BrowseFragment will be reloaded with new data.
Is this recommended?

Answer (score 1):

Well the `HeadersFragment` in the `BrowseFragment` acts a lot like a `ListView` (since it's backed by a `VerticalGridView` which is backed by a `RecyclerView`) which lets you map your selections in the `HeadersFragment` to the fragments controlled by your `BrowseFragment`.

I cover the below in more depth in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37800789/1759443), but here is the gist:

With version `24.0.0` of the Leanback library, you can map a single `HeaderItem` (in the `HeadersFragment`) to multiple `ListRow`s by using the `PageRowFragmentFactory`. If you map the `HeaderItem` to a `RowsFragment` (or any type of fragment for that matter) and populate that `RowsFragment` with multiple rows, then it sounds like it might be able to achieve what you described in your OP.

The `BrowseFragment` will handle all of the refreshing for you. So all you have to do is tell it what list item in the headers section maps to which fragment and it'll swap the fragments out for you. You should really clone the [leanback showcase example app](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase) and play around with it in an emulator to see if it's what you're looking for.